# Blank screen on Loading document fom uri in Expo's webview

Tags: android, react-native, webview, expo, react-native-webview

I am using Expo .
`import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";`
and imported webview like above i am trying to load a document file from some https url , it is working fine and loading the xls file in IOS but in android it giving a blank screen.

```js
 <WebView
  originWhitelist={["*"]}
  source={{ uri: 'https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/4/E/14EDED28-6C58-4055-A65C-23B4DA81C4DE/Financial%20Sample.xlsx' }}
  onLoadEnd={() =>  console.log('end' +Platform.OS)}
  javaScriptEnabled={true}
  domStorageEnabled={true}
  useWebKit={true}
  style={styles.WebViewStyle}
  startInLoadingState={true}
/>

const styles = {  
  WebViewStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    marginLeft: 6,
    height: "50%",
    width: "97%"
  }
}
```

console.log of  onLoadEnd is not coming for android but working fine for IOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Linking, as WebView is a view that display web pages inside your application.

```
import * as Linking from 'expo-linking';

Linking.openURL('https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/4/E/14EDED28-6C58-4055-A65C-23B4DA81C4DE/Financial%20Sample.xlsx');
```

Comment: Yes i can do this , but this doesn't solve my purpose.
I want to open the document in my app on new screen .
My approach is working fine with IOS but i can't figure out  why not on android.

Comment: have you mentioned these props?

<WebView
    source={{ uri: "http://myinitialurl.com.br/arquivos/" }}
    style={{}}
    startInLoadingState={true}
    allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={true}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    mixedContentMode={'always'}
    onNavigationStateChange={(result) => 
    this.handleUrlWithZip(result)}
/>

Comment: <WebView
          originWhitelist={["*"]}
          source={{
            uri: loadUri, headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/pdf",
            }
          }}
          style={styles.WebViewStyle}
          startInLoadingState={true} 
          allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={true} 
          javaScriptEnabled={true} 
          mixedContentMode={'always'}
          onLoadStart={() => activityIndicatorLoadingView}
          startInLoadingState={true}
        />

yes but i am not having any use of onNavigationStateChange not used that

Comment: Thanks for taking your time out for helping me .
I have created a snak link for you so that you can understand what is happening actually .
When you will run this you will find that it is working fine in IOS but not in android: 

https://snack.expo.io/@gd_11/874548

Please have a look  and help.